# Java script to display label

Tags: javascript, html

I've try to make the label "until" appear when user select for "range". But the label did not appear.
These are my codes.

```
           <td><select onchange="Show(this,'vin','until1');"
        <option value="less">Less than</option>
        <option value="more">More than</option>
        <option value="range">By range</option>
        <option value="is">Is anything</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="145"><input id="vin" style="visibility:hidden;" type="text"></td>
    <td width="145"><label id="until1" style="display:none;"> until </label> </td>

  txt=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
  if (txt.match('range')){
  document.getElementById(un).show();}
```

Thanks

Comment: That label is missing its `for` attribute.

Comment: You need to show me your "Show" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show()` is method in jquery not in javascript.. try this

```
document.getElementById(un).style.display = 'block';
```

or in case of `visibility`

```
document.getElementById(un).style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: thanks...i've tried using visible and it work...btw,thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of show(), do style.display = 'block'